# Uncertainty in measurement error

Tags: measurement-error, uncertainty

Imagine having a list of positions $\mathbf{x}$ and two different systems trying to estimate $\mathbf{x}$. One system is more precise than the other, and it will be used as ground truth. When measuring a position, it gives a result
$$
\mathbf{\alpha_i}\sim \mathbf{N}(x_i, 1).
$$
The second system is less precise, it gives a measurement
$$
\beta_i\sim\mathbf{N}(x_i, 3).
$$
The first system is considered to be ground truth because it is the best system we have. We now want to evaluate how well the second system works. To do this, we measure a large number of positions independently with both systems, take the difference between the results of the first and second system, and compute the percentage of differences which is smaller than a cut-off, e.g. smaller than 6.

Here is a computer simulation of the problem written in Python:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

real = 100 * np.random.rand(100000)
gt = [np.random.normal(loc=x, scale=1) for x in real]
estimates = [np.random.normal(loc=x, scale=3) for x in real]

diff = np.array([np.abs(x - y) for x, y in zip(gt, estimates)])

plt.hist(diff, bins=100, density=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: Histogram]

```
len(diff[diff < 6])/len(diff)
# Out: 0.94366
```

**And the question is**: What is the uncertainty of 0.94366 the uncertainty in the ground truth? Essentially, how do I compute the uncertainty of the area under the curve of the histogram above, to the left of $x=6$.

Note that the estimates, the values of the second system, are what they are. Even though they follow an error distribution, this distribution is not known and we don't wish to take it into consideration since the very point of this exercise is to find out how well the second system works.

Comment: If you're just interested in computing the area under your histogram, you could just [fit a function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html) to the data and integrate that function in the desired interval

Comment: @Rickyfox Sorry, that was a mistake. I meant to ask, if I compute the area under the  histogram, what is the standard deviation of that area?

Comment: Have you considered repeating your computer experiment, say 100 times?

Comment: @Estacionario The simulation is just an example. The real life scenario is that I have two hardware systems. I want to evaluate the performance of one hardware system by using the other as ground truth. I cannot repeat the real-life physical experiment 100 times.

Comment: @C.E. what do you mean by the standard deviation of the area under the histogram?

Comment: @Rickyfox Each time I run the simulation, I'm going to get a new value for the area under the histogram for which $x < 6$ (or some other cut-off.) One time maybe it is 93.1, another 95.2, another 94.7, etc. So what is the standard deviation of those values if I were to run the simulation a hundred times? Since I cannot run my physical experiment a hundred times I would like to know, if possible, with some reasonable assumptions, what is the uncertainty (the standard deviation) of this area measurement when I run an experiment.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "ground truth" and what the point of counting small differences might be?

Comment: @whuber sorry, I missed your comment. Imagine you want to sell a system to a customer. That customer wants to know what performance he can expect. You tell him that "95% of the measurements will have less than 1 cm error". In order to compute the error of the measurements done by the system, you need an even better system. That better system is the "ground truth". I'm asking this question because I'm concerned about the effect of having a "ground truth" that also has an error. I wonder what that means for the fraction of errors less than a threshold.

Comment: @whuber It's not just that you've told the customer to expect that performance. In fact, you are legally obligated to provide a system with that performance. This makes it even more important to understand what the effect of having a "ground truth" system with an error is, esp. if there are problems with this approach that could systematically affect whether the system performance beats the threshold.

Comment: I'm lost here, because I cannot see anything in the question that models what you are talking about.  Your two systems are perfectly *accurate* but have different *known* levels of *precision.*  The disconnect between what you are asking and what you stipulate in your model leads me to suspect that your model does not correctly express what you know.

Comment: @whuber If I'm not making sense it is because I don't know better. Yes, I know the two measurements exactly. But I also know that they are not exactly correct, they are merely realizations of a random variable. In my model, $x_i$ is the actual true value (as measured by a perfect system) and $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ are the corresponding measurements by the two systems. That's as far as I've gotten with this problem. Do you understand the problem enough based on my previous comment to be able to suggest how I can think more fruitfully about the problem? Any clue would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am wondering whether you truly know the standard deviations of the two measurement systems (you specify that they are 1 and 3) or even whether you know both are accurate.  Could you tell us what the bases of those suppositions are?

Comment: @whuber In order to find that out, the typical method is to apply the same method again: we get a third system which is even better than the other two (it is possible by e.g. putting reflexive stickers on the object we're measuring, but in normal conditions we cannot use it). We assume that this is perfect, and estimate the standard deviation of the other two systems based on this. Then we assume that the standard deviations remain the same in normal working conditions. If we can still reason about the problem with the thresholds without knowing the deviations that would be interesting too.

Comment: @whuber Actually, the systems are calibrated against known measurements to remove systematic error so I think that it is correct to say that this is only matter of precision (and regardless of what the exact precisions are, one system is definitely known to perform much better than the other.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you aiming for but this is 
one approach that might be suitable.
Start with modeling the over 6 error as a probabilistic event.
I.E, lets say that for each measure event $e_i$ there is a $p\in [0, 1]$ probability that true value $x_i$ minus measured value $y_i$ will be lower than 6.
According to this formalization, we are looking at a [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) random variable with parameter $p$, lets name this RV $X$.
Now, in order to estimate $p$ using data we can use maximum likelihood.   This is a common method for parameters estimation, see [this](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs109/reader/11%20Parameter%20Estimation.pdf) for example.
As for the uncertainty, we get it for free from the Bernoulli random variables variance definition - $VAR(X)=p*(1-p)$.